# Without using the if x in y statement and .index function. how do we check for an element from a list in the another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = ['A','B','C','D']
b = ['A','B','E','D']
```

How do I compare list `b` with list `a`? Without using the `if .. in` .. function or the `().index` function. And print out all of the outcomes.

Comment: Why are you restricting to not use if, in, index() function etc?

Comment: Because my assignment restricts me . I can't use this functions as they don't want you to shorten your code. and this functions shorten my codes.

Comment: so i need to know how the if .. in .. function works like the codes to make the function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following solution

```
a=['A','B','C','D'] 
b=['A','B','E','D']
for i in range(len(a)) :
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if a[i]==b[j] :
            print "found"
```

`
or using list comprehension :

```
found=[b[j] for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(b)) if a[i]==b[j]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't unsure on my codes and I found out that I did that solution actually. But I need to compare two lists. And it is hard for me to identify that "E" is not in list "a".As this is a for loop.